# [NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios

try to compare a field returned by web-service and which contains only either the String `true` or `false` (YES, it's STRING and not boolean), so i try to compare it with another string like this :

```
if ([withOptions isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
               annotation.stationLavage=@"with";
           }else {
               annotation.stationLavage=@"without";
           }
```

so when `withOptions` string contains the "true" string, all is ok, and when it contains the "false" string i got this exception in the log :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2984d68'
```

i am pretty sure that in all cases, `withOptions` contains a string value (either "true" or "false") and it never contains NULL.

Comment: You shouldn't be so sure that `withOptions` is always a string. `withOptions` is an instance of `NSNull` when this error is thrown. There are two possible reasons: you're retrieving `withOptions` from a method that may return `+[NSNull null]`, e.g. to indicate not found, or you've corrupted memory and all bets are off.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain me your second reason ? thx

Comment: It would mean that you over-released an object somewhere and a new object was allocated at the same address (an object of a different type).  That can't be what is happening, though, since `+null` returns a singleton that is allocated very early in the app lifecycle.  Barry's first reason is most likely it.

Comment: It's a long shot, but could memory corruption (e.g. an old-school C-style array overrun) write the address of the NSNull class to the `isa` of `withOptions`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i am pretty sure that in all cases,
>   withOptions contains a string value
>   (either "true" or "false") and it
>   never contains NULL.

Clearly, that assumption is wrong. :)

On the line before that `if()` statement, add `NSLog(@"%@ - %@", withOptions, [withOptions class]);`

Not that `NSNull` and `NULL` are not the same thing;  `NSNull` is a class whose singleton instance represents "no value" in containers (and other things) that don't accept `nil` as values.

When that crash occurs, `withOptions` is referring to an instance of `NSNull`.

Comment: Hi , i have already think about it and i test the class of the String `withOptions`and in the log i got `NSCFString`, that's why i would think about Barry's second reason :)

Comment: It would be impossible for `withOptions` to be of type `NSCFString` on the line before the `if()` statement and then crash in the `if()` statement because it turned into an `NSNull`.  It still may be memory corruption, but the bottom line is that `withOptions` contains a reference to an `NSNull` if that `if()` statement is where the actual crash occurred.

Comment: Hi, i try to trach the error and i found that the problem may not came from the isEqual function, please see my new post here, i have explained my problem, thx in advance : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970981/exception-nsnull-isequaltostring-unrecognized-selector-when-i-click-on-callou

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, easy for understand.

```
if ([[info objectForKey:@"address"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
            dto.address    =   @"Unknown";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a safe comparaison and your are not 100% that your "withOption" contains a string , because it could be null for instance (the case where no option has been given) you could do this:

```
if ([@"true" isEqualToString:withAnnotation]) {
     annotation.stationLavage=@"with";
 }else {
     annotation.stationLavage=@"without";
 }
```

Note that you can even shorten the comparaison:

```
annotation.stationLavage=[@"true" isEqualToString:withAnnotation]?@"with":@"without";
```