# Exception [NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector when i click on calloutAccessoryControlTapped

Tags: objective-c, web-services, ios, json

i have a problem with that exception, actually, when i click on the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` button of the pin i got this exception, i try to track the error by the `NSLog` in the console and i found the only pin which caused this exception have the value `<null>`, i explain by some code :

```
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
           NSDictionary *stationEnCours=[array objectAtIndex:i];
           location2D = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){ .latitude = lat, .longitude = lng };
           MyLocation *annotation=[[[MyLocation alloc]initWithName:ensStation distanceVersLaStation:distance coordinate:location2D]autorelease];

//here we set the properties before we get call to addAnnotation annotation.stationAdress=[stationEnCours objectForKey:@"ssiphone_adresse"];
           NSLog(@"%@",annotation.stationAdress);
           [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

i have 4 stations, in the console i got this :

```
2011-05-11 22:27:11.768 TopStation[2370:207] A 51 - Aire de la Champouse
2011-05-11 22:27:11.769 TopStation[2370:207] <null>
2011-05-11 22:27:11.769 TopStation[2370:207] 467 Avenue Henri Mauriat
2011-05-11 22:27:11.769 TopStation[2370:207] Route de Berre - Jas de Bouffan
```

the second one is which cause problem later when i try to click on its `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` so i checked my database and its adress is a `string` and it's not `null`.
i am little confused, why that exception although all is retrieved as `String` ?? i have also tried to do the same work but on the server side and all is ok, it's not displaying me `NULL`, only in the iPhone side and for this station.
If this help, the adress of the station which make problem is :
**1 Boulevard du Maréchal Juin**

Comment: Since nil can't be stored in a collection, your NSDictionary contains NSNull objects instead. When logged, they print `<null>`, so that is indeed where the problem occurs. You can fix this by using `isEqual:` instead of `isEqualToString:` wherever it is used (its not in the code you posted).

Comment: Hi, thx for answering, actually, i didn't understand why and where should i use `isEqual:`; thx :)

Comment: You should use `isEqual:` because your dictionary or array contains a NSNull object. Since `isEqualToString:` is only defined by the NSString class, you cannot use it on a NSNull instance. `isEqual:` is defined for all objects, and will call `isEqualToString:` automatically when called on a string, so it is safe to use. Find anywhere where you use `isEqualToString:` on an object from an array or dictionary and change it to `isEqual:`.

Comment: Hi, i use `isEqualToString` twice on my code and without relation whith `adress`, however, i replaced it to `isEqual`, and my problem still occurs, i didn't understand why only for that adress its getting `<null>` ?

Comment: Is the crash possibly in the MyLocation `initWithName...` method, or something else you call? I cannot tell you why you are getting `<null>` other than that is what is in your collection. It could be helpful if you posted more of the code where the crash is occuring.

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[NSNull isEqualToString:\]: unrecognized selector sent to instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965817/nsnull-isequaltostring-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At some point in your code, you are either calling `isEqualToString:` on an object that you think is an NSString but is really NSNull, or (more likely) you are passing an NSNull to a method/property of a class somewhere that expects a NSString. For example, you might be setting a UILabel's `text` property with the value of `annotation.stationAdress`.

You should generally only use NSNull where you cannot use `nil`, e.g. in an NSArray, NSDictionary, or the like. After extracting the possibly-NSNull value from the collection, you should include a statement like this to convert it back to nil:

```
    if (value == [NSNull null]) value = nil;
```

Comment: Hi, actually, i try to assign the adress value to a label text like this : `adresseStation.text=topStation.sstationAdress;` is this the problem ? and if it's null, why only this, although all data retrieved from web-service are `string` and and finally, where should i test your statement ? thx

Comment: That would be the problem. I have no idea what sort of data you are receiving from the web service or how you are parsing it, so I couldn't begin to tell you why you're getting NSNull. If nothing else, you could insert that test at the point where you assign `sstationAdress`.

Comment: should i do that : `if(topStation.sstationAdress==[NSNUll]){topStation.sstationAdress=nil}adresseStation.text=topStation.sstationAdress;`

Comment: @Malek almost. It's `[NSNull null]`, but you should probably prevent having it in that property in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

Take care while working with tableviews and make sure you are passing the data(array) to tableview datasource and delegate methods.